# Is there a way to know when a new iOS app is released by a specific company?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'd love to know when Kairosoft gets a new game released on iOS.  Is there an app or site that monitors the daily release list against a user supplied criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way is on [AppShopper.com](http://www.appshopper.com/).

- Enter "Kairosoft" in the search box.
- Click on any app title link.
- Scroll to the bottom of the screen and click on the "Other Apps By This Developer" link. This will bring up a custom page for that developer listing all of their app titles and update info.
- A custom RSS feed is also generated in the upper-right corner of the screen. This feed will update for any new app releases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some games are released only in Japanese App Store and AppShopper.com might not notify you.
You can check kairosoft's official site.
Japanese iOS games: http://kairopark.jp/iphone/
English iOS games: http://kairopark.jp/iphone/en/
Hope this helps!